# Can I search for contacts with activity added by specific person?

Tags: activities, search, issues

I am trying to create a smart group for contacts that have **activity** added by specific person.

**Advanced search** allows me to search either
(1) for contacts based on some activity;
(2) for activities based on **who** has added the activity.

But unfortunately not for contacts based on who has added the activity.

**UPDATE:** (Tested on CiviHosting demo site.)

Advanced search parameters:

- Display Results As: **Contacts**
- Basic Criteria - Complete or Partial Name: **Errol**
- Activities: **(*) Added by**

**RESULT:** Search returns **Errol** as the only result, not all contacts whose activities have been added **by Errol**.

[image]

Comment: Seems that in Advanced Search isn't possible to get it. Maybe a bug or an incomplete development? I suspect that the added by filter applies to nothing. But if you try the search as I suggest on https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/18863/104 with Activity Search the filter can be applied correctly.

Comment: @FrancescBassasiBullich Not really, Search Builder returns a lot of false positives.

Comment: I'm not refering to Search Builder. Take a look at **Search > Activity Search**

Comment: Indeed, Activity Search produces correct search results. However, this search can't be saved as a **Smart Group**. Is it a bug that this functionality does not work in Advanced Search?

Answer (score 2):

In Advanced Search and Activity Search you can filter by 'Added by'.

[image: Activity Search form filtered by 'Added by']

Also you can use Search Builder form and filter by 'Activity' with 'Source contact' = ...

[image: Search builder form filtered by activity with source contact]

Comment: It returns me way more contacts that are in any way associated / connected with particular **Source Contact** (either if I indicate name or email).

Comment: Maybe a bug? Anyway I edited answer adding an alternative way but that contradicts the description of the question you do.

Comment: Aivars - perhaps confirm on one of the demo sites to help confirm if this is a bug.

Comment: @petednz-fuzion Is it a bug or expected behavior? I updated the initial post to include a quick test on the demo site.

Answer (score 1):

Based on a very quick test Search Builder may give you what you want eg
[image]

Comment: oh i see my answer is same as Francesc - maybe grab my image and put in his answer?

Comment: On CiviHosting demo site (https://civicrm.demo.civihosting.com/civicrm) I open **Search Builder**. I setup the search like in your screenshot, only the Source Contact ID is **38** (i.e., **Adams, Errol**). It returns me a list of different contacts like Adams, Kenny / Adams, Rolando and so on. When I click on these contacts, I can't find any reference whatsoever about Activities connected with **Errol** (Source Contact ID=38).

**Is it a bug?**

Comment: I concur that using Search Builder and Source Contact ID is not giving the expected result